# Where did sessionManagement go in webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

In spring web I can use sessionManagement as show below. However in webflux im not able to find any information on how to do this type of session management.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.NEWER)
}
```

My question is how do I do the following setup in webflux???